# Follow up: Collection of half open intervals is an algebra, why?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

The questions "[i have to show, why the collection of all finite unions of such half open intervals (a,b] is an algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735621/collection-of-half-open-intervals-is-an-algebra-why)" has been mostly answered, but i don't understand the following part:

"For 1, let $A = \cup_{i = 1}^n A_i$ for some finite $\{A_i,...,A_n\} \subseteq A_0$. For each i let $A_i=(a_i,b_i]$ (with suitable adjustment for unbounded intervals). You can assume without loss of generality that
$b_i < a_{i + 1}$ (why?). So all you need to do is find a convenient form for the complement of A, and you're done!"

I don't succeed in constructing the half open intervals in such a way that their complement is not half open again.

Comment: Presumably, this is a follow up to some question in Math Stack Exchange. You should reference it so we can provide an adequate answer

Comment: Just added the link.

Comment: But ... to prove it is an algebra, you have to prove that the complement of a finite union of those half-open intervals is *again* a finite union of those half-open intervals! Why are you even trying to prove the opposite (i.e. construct a counterexample)?

Comment: Take an example. Let's start from $(-\infty, 3]\cup (5,6]$. What is its complement? $(3, 5]\cup(6,+\infty)$ - again a finite union of half-open intervals of the same type.

Comment: If $A$ is the union of finitely many half-open intervals, let $n$ be the least $n'\in \Bbb N$ such that $A$ is the union of $n' $ half-open intervals. So  $A=\cup_{i=1}^n(a_i,b_i]$ where $a_i\le a_{i+1}$ whenever $i+1\le n. $ If  $b_i\le a_{i+1}$ for some $i$ then $(a_i,b_i]\cup (a_{i+1},b_{i+1}]=(a_i, \max (b_i,b_{i+1})]$ so we could replace the pair $(a_i,b_i], (a_{i+1},b_{i+1}]$ with the single interval $(a_i, \max (b_i,b_{i+1})]$ and present $A$ as a union of $n-1$ half-open intervals, contrary to the minimality of $n.$ That is why "WLOG $b_i<a_{i+1}$".

Comment: TYPO. In my previous  comment, "If $b_i\le a_{i+1}$ for some $i$" should be "If $b_i\ge a_{i+1}$ for some $i$"....To continue my previous comment: In other words if $A\ne\emptyset$ is a finite union of half-open intervals then there $exists$ some $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ and some $(a_1,b_1],...,(a_n,b_n]$ with $b_i<a_{i+1}$ when $i+1\le n$ and with $A=\cup_1^n(a_i,b_i].$

Comment: makes sense. but what is "convenient form for the complement of A"?